# Simple header file visibility confusion in C

Tags: c, header

I have a strange problem in C about including header files.

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "location.h"

int waste_new_line();

int main()
{
    location *crossroads = malloc(sizeof(*crossroads));
...
```

*location.h*

```
typedef struct Location_Struct location;
```

*location.c*

```
typedef struct Location_Struct {
    int ID;
    char *name;
    char *description;
} location;

int setup_location(location* l, char* name)
{
    ...
```

Now this isn't working because

```
location *crossroads = malloc(sizeof(*crossroads));
```

is throwing an error:dereferencing pointer to incomplete type meaning that it can see the contents of location.h, yet it doesn't seem to be aware of location.c...

I've looked around and all the tutorials I've seen say that the linker will link both files together.

EDIT:

I have altered the code to include an initializer inside location.c as so:

*main.c*

```
...
#include "location.h"

int waste_new_line();

int main()
{

    location *crossroads = initialize_location();
    ....
```

*location.h*

```
typedef struct Location_Struct location;

location* initialize_location();
```

*location.c*

```
...
typedef struct Location_Struct {
    int ID;
    char *name;
    char *description;
} location;

location* initialize_location(location* l)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(location));
}
...
```

This is still throwing the same error, yet only when I try and access the members of crossroads using:

```
crossroads->description
```

this will throw the *deferencing to incomplete type* error.

EDIT 2: For now I've decided to just put the struct definition in the header file...

Comment: location *crossroads = malloc(sizeof(location));

Comment: The files are linked together, but not by the compiler (or at least not by the part of the compiler than concerns itself with your C source code). Which tutorials state something else?

Comment: @Krister: No, the OP's method should be preferred.

Comment: @delnan: sorry I meant the linker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is expected.  When you `#include "location.h"`, only the header file is visible to the compiler.  The `location.c` file comes along later, at link time.

You have two options:

1. Add a function, which you declare in `location.h` and define in `location.c`, which does the necessary `malloc` and returns a pointer.
2. Move the full definition of the struct to the header file.

Comment: Would number 2 be an option if I needed to use location as parameters of functions in location.c?

I would have to include location.h again to be able to access the data structure in both location.c, would that be bad practise?

Comment: @JoeBentley: It is standard practice to include `.h` in the corresponding `.c`.  That way, the compiler can check that your function declarations and definitions match.

Answer (score 2):

The `main` file knows about a `struct` called `Location_Struct` (and a typedef). It has no idea how big it is, thus you can't apply `sizeof` to it.

Since you are effectively hiding the layout and the implementation of `Location_Struct` it makes sense to provide a "constructor" that allocates it.

#### EDIT

It seems I have to mention that by "constructor" I mean an ordinary function that has access to the implementation of the structure and can allocate and possibly pre-populate the object.

Comment: `C` does not have constructors.

Comment: -1 For trying to justify and pass off the usage of term `constructor` which by no means is standard nor popular nor common in `C`.A mere acceptance of slipage would have sufficed.

Comment: @Als: I think you're being too harsh.  Using constructor-like functions in pure C is a very sensible design pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to make a function that does that or simply include the full struct definition in location.h

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `constructor like function` would be a valid usage instead of `constructor` which is very likely to mislead a new user to be giving funny ideas about something that does not exist.

Comment: @Als It's interesting that you downvoted *after* I edited my answer, making clear what I meant by `constructor`.

Comment: The term *constructor* is perfectly fine here and makes a lot of sense unless your linguistic capabilities haven't developed above machine level.

Comment: @JoeBentley Ask yourself: does main really need to access the members of the struct directly ? If not, make a function.

Comment: It was downvoted for saying **It seems I have to mention that by "constructor"** it seems to imply that everyone should be aware of what a constructor in c is, and you have to explain since doubt are being raised about it,which is incorrect since nothing like that exists in c.Change it and I will remove my downvote as well as the comments on the same.

Comment: @cnicutar: Okay so if I have a function that returns type location*, and returns return malloc(sizeof(location)); in location.c, and then in main.c use location *crossroads = initialize_location(); then that should work right?

Comment: Okay that method is still giving me the same error, but only when I try and indirectly access members of the struct pointer.

Comment: @JoeBentley What do you mean by "indirectly" ? Please edit your question and add the updated code. You need to have a bit of patience :-)

Comment: I've done so, by "indirectly" I mean the indirect member access operator: ->

Comment: @JoeBentley That is what I meant by "directly" :-), but it's OK that we have established a lingua franca. More to the point, if you intend to access fields from main (rather than using "acessor" functions - getters and setters) then you probably want to expose the definition of the structure.

Comment: You can do that in C? I never thought of using getters and setters outside of Object Orientated Programming.

I've added the edited code to my original post, I'm completely clueless to why it doesn't work...

Comment: @JoeBentley What I mean by accessors is ordinary functions that receive the object as the first parameter. Anyways, my advice at the moment is to simply expose the structure in the header.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5945/discussion-between-joe-bentley-and-cnicutar)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the definition of `Location_Struct` in the header file location.h.  The compiler would not "see" the other source file (unless it were #include'd, which would not typically be a good idea).

Comment: But then I have to #include location.h in location.c too as functions in location.h take type location as parameters, is it bad practise to #include location.h in location.c as well as main.c? It _would_ solve my problem, but I'm cautious about whether it's a good idea or not, I don't want it to cause me trouble in the future...

Comment: @JoeBentley: That is actually the correct thing to do.  Every source file that uses a structure needs its full definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cleared up any worries I had.